# What is the official title for a software automation engineer?

Tags: title, position

We are looking to add a position for a software automation engineer. The automation is mainly automated internal processes such as manual daily database jobs, and helping our tech support department have less "busy" work.

This may sound like a dumb question, but what are they called? Initially for the role we figured Automation Engineer, but we quickly realized we would be getting the wrong applicants. An Automation Engineer automates mechanical automation. We are looking for someone to database and app automation. Software Automation Engineer seems like a logical step, but is that the actual name of the field/job/profession?

Does anyone know what the correct title for this is?

Comment: Ummm... Software Automation Engineer? or maybe Software/Process Automation Engineer?

Comment: Software Automation Engineer

Comment: The problem you are going to have, it people use the term "engineer" instead of analyst. A lot of QA Engineers are just QA Analysts that want to have Engineer in their title, even though most of their time is running manual test cases. It sounds like you want an actual QA Engineer.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the automation you are going for. There is QA automation, Automation in general, Infrastructure automation, Robotics process automation, Continuous deployment and Continuous integration (which is deployment automation).

Rather than focusing on the title, I recommend fine tuning your description, to make sure applicants know what sort of work or application they are automating.

Comment: Good point - I've updated the question to help answer that. But you're right, the description can explain away the ambiguity.

Comment: @NickTydryszewski I'm not 100% about automating database jobs to be manual (I assume you have the sql statements and just need to trigger it). You could go with Robotics Process Automation or RPA, which basically automates manual software related work in general.

Comment: When I started reading the question I thought "Duh, devops!", then quickly decided I was wrong. So, definitely be sure the job description matches the job you're attempting to hire for.

Comment: @JulieinAustin I always thought DevOps roles combined the traditional Developer role along with Operational Testing and Deployment. Automation is a big part of Devops, but not a necessity. Sort of like a Fullstack Dev, which does back-end, front-end and deployments.

Comment: @Shadowzee - I've worked with DevOps people, but I really don't know what they do. A lot of it sounds like "automate all kinds of things that people used to do, but now there are 100 times as many servers and we cant hire that many people." That stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your favorite job search sites and see what others are using for title, descriptions and keywords for similar positions.

You want to make it possible that people with those skills can find your posting. If you don't make it easy for them to find you, they will not be the ones applying.

I always am amazed how hard it can be to find the jobs I am qualified for among all the non-specific titles and descriptions.